# Wordpress Multi-site, different dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking into using Wordpress Multi-site to have a three separate wordpress sites on one installation of Wordpress.

I have the Mulit-site set up and I can add sites but I have one admin log in to the multi site Dashboard showing all the sites.

Is it possible to have separate logins that login into the separate sites.

So if I have a cars website it would have it's own dashboard that the cars-admin could log into but wouldn't be able to see the multi-site dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'Super Admin' role has access to all sites on your network. The 'Administrator' role has access to all features within a single site. For each site on your network, you could create a new user and assign that user an 'Administrator' role.

See this article for more info:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Summary_of_Roles